# Anyone know how to fix the linux 3 2018 anaconda x86_64 installer?

Tags: anaconda

The installer has a conda.sh script which we are supposed to source to add the bins to your path but I don't see an assignment for PATH in it.  I can't find an older installer.  Any help is appreciated.

fwiw, here is what the installer says to do and here is my result

```
You may wish to edit your /home/davis/.bashrc to setup Anaconda3:

source /home/davis/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

Thank you for installing Anaconda3!
```

and if you do that, here is the result

```
davis@twenty:~$ source /home/davis/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
davis@twenty:~$ anaconda
bash: anaconda: command not found
davis@twenty:~$ anaconda-navigator
bash: anaconda-navigator: command not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you source conda.sh, do this

```
$ conda activate
```

Then you can start navigator

```
$ anaconda-navigator
```